# iOS Instagram - How to obtain access token for public feed without login

Tags: ios, authentication, feed, access-token, instagram

How can I grab the Instagram feed (message, pictures and videos) by using generated access token **without login**?

I have read the [Instagram Developers documentation](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#) and found out that users really need to login in order to retrieve someone's public contents/feed.

Facebook and Twitter have their own clientId and clientSecret and both of them have full filled their own purposes, to get access token and the feed without user's login.

But since Instagram has its own clientID and client Secret too, and strangers can view one's public photos/feed without login on web browser, why the hell we still need to login to get the access token, in order to get the feed in json format??

Am I missing something?

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Anyone that can help? Nope?

Comment: do you found a way how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible, the only way to get an access token if you log in, but, you can do a hack to not request an access token

well, you need request an access token with your account, when you get it, set this access token in your app and do all request with that access token, but when that access token expire  request a new one.

here a framework when i use this hack, and request a new access token when the old one is expired

https://github.com/Busta117/SBInstagram

Comment: can i renew this particular users access token using own clientID and client Secret without user login. user is already authenticated but access token is expire. so can we make like that access token is renew ago it's expire.?